# Is it possible to recall a function every x seconds at flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to recall a function every x seconds at flutter?  And notify if there are changes?
the code is as follows

````
  List<Any> any =
      await Api.getAny(++widget.appState.lastPage, widget.datauser);
  widget.appState.issues.addAll(issues);
  setState(() {});
}```
````

Answer (score 4):

Actually It is easy to run function every x amount of seconds on flatter.
You can use Timer to recall function per x seconds.

```
Timer timer;

void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t) => checkForNewSharedLists());
}

void dispose() {
  timer.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Executing with Timer, it would load the entire array or the array would be added on array

Comment: at the following direction, it explains a similar solution, but I can't get it to work
https://github.com/fayeed/dash_chat/blob/master/lib/src/models/reply.dart

Comment: main.dart

    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        if (widget.appState.items.isEmpty) {
          getMoreItems();
        }
        {
          timer =
              Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t) => getMoreItems());
        }
      }
    
...
    
      getNextItems() async {
        List<Item> item =
            await Api.getNextItems(++widget.appState.lastPage);
        widget.appState.items.add(item);
        setState(() {});
      }

Comment: api.dart

      static Future<List<Item>> getNextItem(int page) async {
    
        http.Response response = await http.get(popularUrl(Items));
    
        Map<String, dynamic> decoded = json.decode(response.body);
    
        List<dynamic> list = decoded['data'];
      }

Comment: class.dart

class Item {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Item({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = int.parse(json['id']),
        name = int.parse(json['name']);
}